# How to add ssl certificate in couchbase android programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, ssl, couchbase-lite

Below is my code:

```
   database = Utils.inializeDb(HomeActivity.this, "company-3");

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("https://*********/db_name");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Replication push = database.createPushReplication(url);
    Replication pull = database.createPullReplication(url);


    Authenticator auth = AuthenticatorFactory.createBasicAuthenticator("admin", "1m2p3k4n");
    pull.setAuthenticator(auth);

    push.setContinuous(true);
    pull.setContinuous(true);


    pull.start();
```

I want to add ssl Certificate in this code..

Below is error code;

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:366)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.kt:351)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.kt:310)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.kt:178)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:236)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.kt:109)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.kt:77)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange$okhttp(Transmitter.kt:162)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:35)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
>           at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:82)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:84)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:71)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:112)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:87)
>           at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.kt:184)
>           at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:66)
>           at com.couchbase.lite.replicator.RemoteRequest.executeRequest(RemoteRequest.java:262)
>           at com.couchbase.lite.replicator.RemoteRequest.execute(RemoteRequest.java:166)
>           at com.couchbase.lite.replicator.RemoteRequest.run(RemoteRequest.java:106)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>        Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:549)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:401)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:375)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:304)
>           at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
>           at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:88)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:178)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:611)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
>           at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:362)

Answer (score 1):

From errors, it looks like the Sync Gateway cert from a well-known trusted CA or it was perhaps self-signed. How was the cert issued? Follow the steps [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl) to configure your system to accept the cert.

Any reason you are starting with 1.x version of Couchbase Lite? Version 1.x is EoL for almost a year. You should switch to [2.x](https://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-lite/2.6/java.html).